# Free jqGrid restoring date with custom formatter after cancelling inline edit

Tags: date, formatter, free-jqgrid, inline-editing

After inline edit is cancelled, the date column comes back as undefined instead of restoring the original value. Column is defined as following (dates are coming in `1970-01-01` format):

```
{name:'Release<br>Date',index:'Street_Date', sorttype:"date", width:70,
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return cellvalue === ('1970-01-01') ? "" : $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "date", cellvalue, options, rowObject);
    },
    formatoptions: {newformat:'d M y'},
    editable:true,
    editoptions: {
        size:9, 
        dataInit: function(el, options) { 
                $(el).datepicker({ 
                    dateFormat: "d M y",
                    defaultDate: '01 Jan 70',
                    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    }
                });
        } 
    },
    searchoptions: {
        sopt: ['eq','ne','ge','le'],
        dataInit: function (elem) { 
            $(elem).datepicker({ showButtonPanel: true, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }) 
            } 
        }
},
```

The inline edit is setup as following:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    var savedRows = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");

    if (savedRows.length > 0 && savedRows[0].id !== rowid) {
        // cancel editing 
        $grid.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRows[0].id);
    }
    if (savedRows.length === 0) {
        $grid.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, editOptions);
    }
}
```

When Grid is loaded, the date shown like `07 Aug 18`, entering the inline editing by double click, the date is still `07 Aug 18`. After cancelling the edit either by clicking away or clicking Cancel button, date becomes `NaN undefined N`. After refresh, it comes back correctly though.

How to preserve the correct date after cancelling editing?
Grid behaves correctly with `formatter: date`

free jqGrid v jqGrid 4.13.5

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used  - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid ver <=4.7?

Comment: @Tony Tomov, sorry, it's  jqGrid 4.13.5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the author of free-jqGrid will help better, but I would recommend you to add additional parameter (action='edit') when the formatter is called. Code below:

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return cellvalue === ('1970-01-01') ? "" : $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "date", cellvalue, options, rowObject, "edit");
},
```

Note the last parameter in $.fn.fmatter.call

**UPDATE**

This is working in my tests.
Since you use a custom date fomatter it is needed the value in savedRows to be unformated in order to be saved correct. In case of default formatter = date this is done automatically.

Below is the code that can be used, suppose you know the index of the field in colModel:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    var savedRows = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");

    if (savedRows.length > 0 && savedRows[0].id !== rowid) {
        // cancel editing 
        savedRows[0].Release_Date = $.unformat.date.call($grid[0], savedRows[0].Release_Date,  $grid[0].p.colModel[1]);
        $grid.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRows[0].id);
    }
    if (savedRows.length === 0) {
        $grid.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, editOptions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not have any impact, but just wanted to say personal THANK YOU to both you and Oleg

Comment: Yes, I see your logic here, or I could just copy and reinstate the original value, however, `ondblClickRow` is not called, when one just clicks away anywhere in the grid (i.e. away from current row in edit mode) or clicks `Cancel` button...

Comment: As I explain in the update - the restoreRow calls setRowData to set the values in case there is no change - i.e. when cancel buton, esc key and etc. setRowData in case of formatter date automatically convert to original date in order to preserve confusions, but you use custom date formatter. To overcome this it is needed to reformat the date with custom code after every editRow in savedRow array.  I have just put a example. To resolve fully the problem it is needed to reformat the date field in savedRow after every editRow.

Comment: sorry for such delay and thank you for your help. I was away for a while... Further experiments show that the problem occurs only with `formatoptions: {newformat:'d M y'},`, when I changed it to `formatoptions: {newformat:'Y-m-d'},` it works absolutely as expected. Would you know why? Is it because of the spaces? Without any `formatoptions`, the default date format is american style `7/27/2018` and also works fine